# How to dynamically generate array of dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, dictionary, boto3

I am using boto3 API for automatically addition partitions to a glue table. For creating one single partition, I am able to use create_partition api which requires me to specify one dictionary like below as input.

```
PartitionInput = {
                        'Values': [
                            '2018', '08', '25', '06'
                        ],
                        'StorageDescriptor': {
                            'Location': 'some_location/2018/08/25/06',
                            'InputFormat': 'input_format',
                            'OutputFormat': 'output_format',
                            'SerdeInfo': 'serde_info'
                        }
                    }
```

Now, I want to use batch_create_partition API where I need to specify an array of above dict for create multiple partitions together. So If a user inputs 25 Aug 2018 (start date) and 3 as number of partitions, then my array should contain 3 values where each value is the above dict but which changing values and location. So output will be -

```
PartitionInput = [{
    'Values': [
      '2018', '08', '25', '00'
    ],
    'StorageDescriptor': {
      'Location': 'some_location/2018/08/25/06',
      'InputFormat': 'input_format',
      'OutputFormat': 'output_format',
      'SerdeInfo': 'serde_info'
    }
  },
  {
    'Values': [
      '2018', '08', '25', '01'
    ],
    'StorageDescriptor': {
      'Location': 'some_location/2018/08/25/06',
      'InputFormat': 'input_format',
      'OutputFormat': 'output_format',
      'SerdeInfo': 'serde_info'
    }
  }, {
    'Values': [
      '2018', '08', '25', '03'
    ],
    'StorageDescriptor': {
      'Location': 'some_location/2018/08/25/06',
      'InputFormat': 'input_format',
      'OutputFormat': 'output_format',
      'SerdeInfo': 'serde_info'
    }
  }
]
```

I am new to python as well as programming so I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the above problem using below code -

```
for x in range(24):
    year = 2018
    month = 02
    day = 25
    hour = x
    part_loc = "some_location/{}/{}/{}/{}".format(year, month, day, hour)
    input_dict = {
        'Values': [
            str(year), str(month), str(day), str(hour)
        ],
        'StorageDescriptor': {
            'Location': part_loc,
            'InputFormat': 'input_format',
            'OutputFormat': 'output_format',
            'SerdeInfo': 'serde_info'
        }
    }

    input_list.append(input_dict.copy())

print input_list
```